# flutter firebase googlesign in says - A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

I know the same has been posted here, but doesn't seem to have an answer. I am having this red line underneath the GoogleSignIn, somewhere there has been a mention about downgrading the google_sign_in package version from 5.0.4 to 5.03, that hasn't helped me get rid of this error. here is my code so far -

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GoogleSignIn().signIn()` return GoogleSignInAccount? which means it might be null. On the other hand your `googleUser` variable is of type GoogleSignInAccount which means it can't be null. you should refactor your code to look like this:

```
Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = GoogleSignIn().signIn();
  
  if (googleUser != null) {
     // Rest of the code
     ...
  }
}
```